# How to programmatically generate the CREATE TABLE SQL statement for a given model in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, migration

I need to programmatically generate the CREATE TABLE statement for a given **unmanaged** model in my Django app (`managed = False`)

Since i'm working on a legacy database, i don't want to create a migration and use `sqlmigrate`.

The `./manage.py sql` command was useful for this purpose but it has been removed in Django 1.8

Do you know about any alternatives?

Comment: What flavor database? Some like MySQL allow you to execute a "SHOW CREATE TABLE" statement

Comment: May I ask why you need to "programmatically generate" this SQL statement when it's an unmanaged model ? If the point is to create a dev database, creates a schema-only SQL dump from the original (or ask the dba to do so) and include it in your source.

Comment: If your end goal is to have a table created, e.g. for some testing, take a look at a way to force Django create it for you at specific moment, e.g. test class setup, without handling the raw SQL yourself [`BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor.create_model(model)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/schema-editor/#create-model).

Comment: @Nikita you should really post an answer so anyone can vote you for this great answer. If it works (I have not tested it), it is a wonderful solution compared to the one I gave one year ago ;-)

Comment: @fero, thanks :) Will do. It works. I stumbled upon this question, when I needed to mock a read-only view of external system to test my model. Looking at your answer, I understood, that I forgot to think about using the Django migration framework API. Conducting more search over the docs lead me to using the method I pointed out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested, I post a complete answer for the case, that the question might imply.

Suppose you have an external DB table, that you decided to access as a Django model and therefore have described it as an unmanaged model ([`Meta: managed = False`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#managed)).
Later you need to be able to create it in your code, e.g for some tests using your local DB. Obviously, Django doesn't make migrations for unmanaged models and therefore won't create it in your test DB.
This can be solved using Django APIs without resorting to raw SQL - [`SchemaEditor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/schema-editor/). See a more complete example below, but as a short answer you would use it like this:

```
   from django.db import connections

   with connections['db_to_create_a_table_in'].schema_editor() as schema_editor:
        schema_editor.create_model(YourUnmanagedModelClass)
```

A practical example:

```
# your_app/models/your_model.py

from django.db import models

class IntegrationView(models.Model):
    """A read-only model to access a view in some external DB."""

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'integration_view'

    name = models.CharField(
        db_column='object_name',
        max_length=255,
        primaty_key=True,
        verbose_name='Object Name',
    )
    some_value = models.CharField(
        db_column='some_object_value',
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name='Some Object Value',
    )

    # Depending on the situation it might be a good idea to redefine
    # some methods as a NOOP as a safety-net.
    # Note, that it's not completely safe this way, but might help with some
    # silly mistakes in user code

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Preventing data modification."""
        pass

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Preventing data deletion."""
        pass
```

Now, suppose you need to be able to create this model via Django, e.g. for some tests.

```
# your_app/tests/some_test.py

# This will allow to access the `SchemaEditor` for the DB
from django.db import connections
from django.test import TestCase
from your_app.models.your_model import IntegrationView

class SomeLogicTestCase(TestCase):
    """Tests some logic, that uses `IntegrationView`."""

    # Since it is assumed, that the `IntegrationView` is read-only for the
    # the case being described it's a good idea to put setup logic in class 
    # setup fixture, that will run only once for the whole test case
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """Prepares `IntegrationView` mock data for the test case."""

        # This is the actual part, that will create the table in the DB
        # for the unmanaged model (Any model in fact, but managed models will
        # have their tables created already by the Django testing framework)
        # Note: Here we're able to choose which DB, defined in your settings,
        # will be used to create the table

        with connections['external_db'].schema_editor() as schema_editor:
            schema_editor.create_model(IntegrationView)

        # That's all you need, after the execution of this statements
        # a DB table for `IntegrationView` will be created in the DB
        # defined as `external_db`.

        # Now suppose we need to add some mock data...
        # Again, if we consider the table to be read-only, the data can be 
        # defined here, otherwise it's better to do it in `setUp()` method.

        # Remember `IntegrationView.save()` is overridden as a NOOP, so simple
        # calls to `IntegrationView.save()` or `IntegrationView.objects.create()`
        # won't do anything, so we need to "Improvise. Adapt. Overcome."

        # One way is to use the `save()` method of the base class,
        # but provide the instance of our class
        integration_view = IntegrationView(
            name='Biggus Dickus',
            some_value='Something really important.',
        )
        super(IntegrationView, integration_view).save(using='external_db')

        # Another one is to use the `bulk_create()`, which doesn't use
        # `save()` internally, and in fact is a better solution
        # if we're creating many records

        IntegrationView.objects.using('external_db').bulk_create([
            IntegrationView(
                name='Sillius Soddus',
                some_value='Something important',
            ),
            IntegrationView(
                name='Naughtius Maximus',
                some_value='Whatever',
            ),
        ])

    # Don't forget to clean after
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        with connections['external_db'].schema_editor() as schema_editor:
            schema_editor.delete_model(IntegrationView)

    def test_some_logic_using_data_from_integration_view(self):
         self.assertTrue(IntegrationView.objects.using('external_db').filter(
             name='Biggus Dickus',
         ))
```

To make the example more complete... Since we're using multiple DB (`default` and `external_db`) Django will try to run migrations on both of them for the tests and as of now there's no option in DB settings to prevent this. So we have to use a custom DB router for testing.

```
 # your_app/tests/base.py

class PreventMigrationsDBRouter:
    """DB router to prevent migrations for specific DBs during tests."""
    _NO_MIGRATION_DBS = {'external_db', }

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """Actually disallows migrations for specific DBs."""
        return db not in self._NO_MIGRATION_DBS
```

And a test settings file example for the described case:

```
# settings/test.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'PORT': '1521',
    },
    # For production here we would have settings to connect to the external DB,
    # but for testing purposes we could get by with an SQLite DB 
    'external_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    },
}

# Not necessary to use a router in production config, since if the DB 
# is unspecified explicitly for some action Django will use the `default` DB
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['your_app.tests.base.PreventMigrationsDBRouter', ]
```

Hope this detailed new Django user user-friendly example will help someone and save their time.

Answer (score 5):

unfortunately there seems to be no easy way to do this, but for your luck I have just succeeded in producing a working snippet for you digging in the internals of the django migrations jungle.

Just:

1. save the code to `get_sql_create_table.py` (in example)
2. do `$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yourproject.settings`
3. launch the script with `python get_sql_create_table.py yourapp.yourmodel`

and it should output what you need.

Hope it helps!

```python
import django
django.setup()

from django.db.migrations.state import ModelState
from django.db.migrations import operations
from django.db.migrations.migration import Migration
from django.db import connections
from django.db.migrations.state import ProjectState

def get_create_sql_for_model(model):

    model_state = ModelState.from_model(model)

    # Create a fake migration with the CreateModel operation
    cm = operations.CreateModel(name=model_state.name, fields=model_state.fields)
    migration = Migration("fake_migration", "app")
    migration.operations.append(cm)

    # Let the migration framework think that the project is in an initial state
    state = ProjectState()

    # Get the SQL through the schema_editor bound to the connection
    connection = connections['default']
    with connection.schema_editor(collect_sql=True, atomic=migration.atomic) as schema_editor:
        state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor, collect_sql=True)

    # return the CREATE TABLE statement
    return "\n".join(schema_editor.collected_sql)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import importlib
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: {} <app.model>".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(100)

    app, model_name = sys.argv[1].split('.')

    models = importlib.import_module("{}.models".format(app))
    model = getattr(models, model_name)
    rv = get_create_sql_for_model(model)
    print(rv)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Django v4.1.3, the above `get_create_sql_for_model` soruce code changed like this:

```
    from django.db.migrations.state import ModelState
    from django.db.migrations import operations
    from django.db.migrations.migration import Migration
    from django.db import connections
    from django.db.migrations.state import ProjectState
    
    def get_create_sql_for_model(model):
        model_state = ModelState.from_model(model)
        table_name = model_state.options['db_table']
    
        # Create a fake migration with the CreateModel operation
        cm = operations.CreateModel(name=model_state.name, fields=model_state.fields.items())
        migration = Migration("fake_migration", "app")
        migration.operations.append(cm)
    
        # Let the migration framework think that the project is in an initial state
        state = ProjectState()
    
        # Get the SQL through the schema_editor bound to the connection
        connection = connections['default']
        with connection.schema_editor(collect_sql=True, atomic=migration.atomic) as schema_editor:
            state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor, collect_sql=True)
    
        sqls = schema_editor.collected_sql
        items = []
        for sql in sqls:
            if sql.startswith('--'):
                continue
            items.append(sql)
    
        return table_name,items
    
    #EOP
```

I used it to create all tables (like the command `syncdb` of old Django version):

```
    for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        app_name = app.split('.')[0]
        app_models = apps.get_app_config(app_name).get_models()
        for model in app_models:
            table_name,sqls = get_create_sql_for_model(model)

            if settings.DEBUG:
                s = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = '%s'" % table_name
            else:
                s = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_name='%s'" % table_name
            rs = select_by_raw_sql(s)
            if not rs[0]['c']:
                for sql in sqls:
                    exec_by_raw_sql(sql)
                print('CREATE TABLE DONE:%s' % table_name)
```

The full soure code can be found at [Django syncdb command came back for v4.1.3 version](https://gist.github.com/jonahfang/07f9a3cbeaac7e2ebafc3d1dec3ad0ac)